# React router passing id via params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 2 Routes like the following

```
<Route path="/organizations/create" exact component={Component1}/>
<Route path="/organizations/:organizationId" component={Component2}/>
```

However since the `:organizationId` matches with anything when I go to /organizations/create it loads both Component1 and Component2. I want it to load the second component only when the url is like "/organizations/5".

What is an ideal fix for this WITHOUT changing the url (i.e. "organizations/details/:organizationId" would not work - Or is this the only solution)

Comment: wrap the routes in `Switch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Switch`, it will cause only the first matching route to show:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/organizations/create" exact component={Component1}/>
  <Route path="/organizations/:organizationId" component={Component2}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: exact should not come after path

Comment: @omar JSX props are compiled to JavaScript objects, so the order doesn't matter (`{a: 1, b: 2}` is equivalent to `{b: 2, a: 1}`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `exact` keyword

```
<Route exact path="/organizations/create" exact component={Component1}/>
<Route path="/organizations/:organizationId" component={Component2}/>
```